# jmockit expectations NPE

Tags: java, jmockit, expectations

I have this piece of code:

```
new Expectations(){
    {

    mFubar.getModel();
    result = new Model();
    times = 1;

    mFubar.getModel().getAllDogs();
    result = new HashSet<Dogs>();
    times = 1;
    }
};
```

Unfortunately I always get a null value for `mFubar.getModel()`.
How can I create a mock value for `getModel()` so `mFubar.getModel().getAllDogs();` works correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a NPE because the second call to `mFubar.getModel()`, just like the first, returns `null`. You can't use recorded results *inside* an expectation recording block; these values are meant to be obtained from the code under test only.

Besides, it doesn't look like the `Model` class is being mocked here, so trying to record a call to `getAllDogs()` wouldn't work either. For that, you would need to declare a `@Mocked Model model` mock field or mock parameter.

Finally, the default return value for a mocked method having a collection (List, Set, Map, etc.) as its return type already is an empty collection. So, writing `result = new HashSet<Dog>();` would be redundant anyway.